# How to pass arguments into erlang os:cmd()?

Tags: linux, shell, erlang

I want to know how to pass arguments into shell script when use ErLang? I know I can use `os:cmd()` to execute shell script, but I find I can't pass arguments into this command.

For example, I have one argument `L = 2`, and I want my shell script use this argument, so the erlang command should be `os:cmd("bash echo.sh L")`.  However, the output is L, but I want to get 2 instead. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function io_lib:format/2 allow you to prepare a string and then pass it to os:command/1 :

```
S = io_lib:format("bash echo.sh ~p",[L]),
os:cmd(S),
```

`S` is a nested list, I don't remember if it is accepted by `os:cmd/1`, if not you will have to flatten the result `os:cmd(lists:flatten(S))`

Comment: `os:cmd` accepts atoms and deep lists, but not binaries.